# Why does this while loop stop without throwing error?

Tags: python, primes

Trying to find output matching conditions. Iterating through while loop, increasing variable, but program appears to stop when num = 239 and not sure why. When I try each function manually the program works fine.

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return(False)  
                break
        else:
            return(True)

def calc(num):
    x = (num ** num) + 2
    return(x)

def get_next_prime(num):
    num += 1
    while True:
        if is_prime(num):
            return(num)
            break
        else:
            num += 1

def check(num):
    while True:
        if is_prime(calc(num)) and is_prime(num):
            return(num)
            break
        else:
            num = get_next_prime(num)
            print(num)




print(check(4))
```

Expected result is continued iterative output in the form of the next prime number after 239.

Comment: aside: please check on how to compute if a number is prime efficiently.

Comment: I have and this function works. I've tested it with 237, 238, 239, 240 and all are correct outputs.

Comment: In  *is\_prime*, instead of `for i in range(2,num):` you could do `for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(num)) + 1):` That would save you lots of useless calculations. Also *break* after *return* is useless. Also `return(False)` -> `return False`.

Comment: efficiently: I mean you can test if a number is prime by testing the divisors up to the square root of the number, not the number itself.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. This will help you see why it is quitting unexpectedly.

Comment: You have a `break` in your main loop... so your code will stop when that is reached.

Comment: For the purposes of debugging, can you add comments and describe what you think each function does?

For example, in the function `calc`, you are taking a number to the power of itself. It's not clear why that's necessary. Is that what you meant to do? Did you mean to square the number instead?

Additionally, you have a number of `break` statements that immediately follow `return` statements. They are never reached, because `return` statement exits the function. So carefully walk through your code and document each step, and if you get stuck, post clarifying questions.

Answer (score 1):

While is not stopping, its processing. Consuming huge amount of time while process.

```
def is_prime(num):
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return(False)  
            break
    else:
        return(True)
```

Above function is resulting `240^240` is smth like below.

```
42200323427409150751742179532592018252808661114071266629718376939092568551075505740268077803623642715001998769421215763628719631633378375087756319383725641630331895773386010866243028159828607385899087848942302738709343403640250275314218243930567432731458807734886574283968918955323573297631562415292893276034393336066052132808455118105272470307339550216091253570417050545677371810192238471803263478546492058686483752405946094606978411379079233793804753705243644236607675749522119768311584522527886912942059070222789851175661909205254663263392466134105108288691503106
```

In your code `is_prime(calc(num))` is checking every integer starting from 2 to above number. So its consuming time.

As an advice use vscode or other debugging tools.

If you are using print for your debug purposes, replace `print(check(239))`, then put print into line 4 to see your debug result.

```
def is_prime(num):
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        print(i)
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return(False)  
            break
    else:
        return(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that 239 is the first prime where it's non trivial to determine if `239 ** 239 + 2` is a prime.  Prior to that, the calculated numbers failed the prime test easily (multiples of 5, etc.)  Below is my clean up of your code to make it clearer (to me, at least) what's going on.  It includes some of the optimizations suggested in the comments but that makes little difference.  It still bogs down at 239:

```
def is_prime(number):

    if number < 2:
        return False

    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number == 2

    i = 3

    while i * i <= number:
        if number % i == 0:
            return False

        i += 2

    return True

def calculate(odd_prime):
    return odd_prime ** odd_prime + 2

def get_next_odd_prime(odd_number):

    while True:
        odd_number += 2

        if is_prime(odd_number):
            return odd_number

def check(odd_prime):
    while True:
        if is_prime(calculate(odd_prime)):
            return odd_prime

        odd_prime = get_next_odd_prime(odd_prime)

        print(odd_prime)

print(check(5))
```

Since 3 passes this test (`3 ** 3 + 2 == 29` which is also prime), we start at the next higher odd prime as even numbers above 2 make no sense.

Folks may suggest using a sieve of Eratosthenes as a better prime test -- be wary.  Any *simple* sieve implementation that relies on an array structure is going to have problems creating a Python list for as little as `11 ** 11 + 2` or so due to memory allocation issues.  I don't know how much larger a bitvector, that only represents odd numbers say, can go.